# Gulp mocha crashes nodemon

Tags: node.js, tdd, gulp, mocha.js, nodemon

I have a problem with my mocha gulp task. To run the tests, I have to launch the server, and then run the tests. The problem appears when a test fails : nodemon crashes and the node process still running.

Here's my gulpfile:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    mocha = require('gulp-mocha'),
    nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber');

gulp.task('server-dev', function(){
  nodemon({ script: 'server/app.js', ext: 'html js'})
    .on('restart', ['mocha']);
});

gulp.task('mocha', function(){
  return gulp.src('./server/**/*.tests.js', { read: false })
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(mocha());
});
```

When the server crashes, it gives me this message :

```
 uncaughtException: expected 500 to equal 404
 AssertionError: expected 500 to equal 404
 [... stack trace...]
```

How can I do to keep the server running when my test fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found what I wanted!

First, what I didn't know is that Mocha throws an exception when a test fails, and that's what's crashing the server. So I added try/catch almost everywhere in my code, but I found that ugly and it wasn't exactly what I needed.

And then I found [this mocha plugin](https://github.com/KenPowers/gulp-spawn-mocha). With this plugin, when a test fails, only the Mocha process crashes, the server's still running normally.